# How to reset instance variables upon making new instance in python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, instance-variables

I'm trying to program a class called **Box**. It works perfectly except the moment I start making a new instance. I use `__iadd__` magical function to add weights to an instance so the result of this operation is a new instance that inherits some characteristics of an old version of the instance and that's the point. But when I define a completely new object, for example, a new box, then it also inherits those instance variables of an old object clearly that ain't the point. I knew I should program a reset method but is it possible to reset the instance variables just upon making a new instance? Or am I doing something totally wrong that requires a different approach?

Thanks for your help.

```
class Box(object):

masess = [] # Keeps track of masses

weight = 0 # The weight of box

over = 0 # represent the rest capacity of the box

full_boxes = 0 # Number of full boxes


def __init__(self, name, capacity):

    self.name = name

    self.capacity = capacity


def __iadd__(self, other):

    Box.over = self.capacity - other # Determines the capacity of the box after some weights are added.

    if Box.over >=0:

        Box.masess.append(other)

        Box.weight += other

        if Box.weight == self.capacity:

            Box.full_boxes += 1

    return Box(self.name, self.capacity)


def __str__(self):

    return '[%s:%s:C=%i:I=%i]' %(self.name, str(Box.masess), self.capacity,Box.weight)

@staticmethod

def get_aantal_volle_dozen():

    return Box.full_boxes
```

`A = Box('a', 20) #A new box`

```
A +=5 # adding something to the box

A +=8

B = Box('b', 80)

print(B) # oooops!
```

Comment: Your variables are defined as class-level variables (sometimes called "static variables" e.g. in Java), not as instance variables, that is your problem.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga could you please gimme some tips ? Because i'm still confused how to approach it

Comment: Instance variables are accessed using ``self``. The attributes you defined in the class body will be common for all instances. You could move them into ``__init__``

Comment: @Grimmy Thanks. And where should i define those variable if i defined them inside the constructor then after  addition i 'll loos track of everything because `__iadd__` makes a completely new object!

Comment: If you need to share data across all instances use a class-level variable. If you need an instance variable, use an instance variable. Quite frankly, it isn't clear what you want. What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Lemme explain it this way. You define a box put something in it and then you expect to get this  [Box number 1, capacity 20, weight 15] for example and then you define a new box B. If you print B it is already as same as the old Box with the same weight if you could just run the code you'll see it

Comment: @SamFarjamirad you transfer the attributes you want to keep for the new instance.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad You should be *explicit*, editing the question itself, don't add elaboration in the comments. It shouldn't be difficult to give a full example. The one thing you still haven't explained *explicitly* is *exactly what output you expect*. Giving exampes is always a good idea.